# Using Apache Lucene with Infinispan

Tags: lucene, infinispan

Does using Infinispan with Lucene improve the performance of Lucene? There is a RAM Directory included in Lucene itself. Is Infinispan better than RAM Directory?

Comment: Please give some suggestion on above question.

Answer (score 2):

The RAMDirectory provided by Lucene is not really meant for high performance. The filesystem based implementations using NIO and memory map are likely more efficient, unless you're dealing with indexes meant for proof of concepts and unit tests.

The Infinispan Directory is - like the filesystem one - tuned for good performance; it is in fact a bit faster than the filesystem ones to perform write operations (for obvious reasons); the speed race on read performance is a subtle battle, strongly depending on your actual use case.

The main reason to use the Infinispan Directory is not raw performance but:

1. it's capability to replicate and distribute the index across multiple nodes: using shared filesystems for FSDirectory is usually problematic and not fast at all.
2. It's able to work as a caching write-through store to slower persistence services. FS is one, but it might be a relational database, Cassandra, cloud storage services such as S3, ...[write your plugin]
3. It's (optionally) Transactional. You could have it participate in XA transactions if needed.

Comment: You mean to say lucene with file on disk is much faster than the RAM directory?

Comment: Often yes, but of course it depends on many factors, especially index size.